# Use Google's new reCaptcha as a button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, submit, recaptcha

I wrote a contact form and I want to use the "successful" response as submit-button.

I've come up with the idea to check if this statement becomes true:

```
if (grecaptcha.getResponse() != "") { }
```

I just have no idea how. Is there a way to check this statement every second? Would be nice :)

I also tried other methods for validating but noting seems to work correctly.

Some help would be nice ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do this IMO, would be using the callback function from the widget.

```
<script>
var fnSubmit = function(){

//code for submit   

}
</script>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback="fnSubmit"></div>
```

let me know if it works. :)

Comment: works very fine, sorry for the late response :-)  thank you very much!